# Android Studio multiple processes running

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio, while I'm writing code sometime it starts multiple build processes. This eventually slows my PC to the point that it's not possible to do anything until the processes finish.

Is there a way to make it check if a build is already in process and wait for it to finish or abort the previous one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem went away with recent updates to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your project is set to *make* automatically. To do this go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Compiler`, then uncheck `Make project automatically`. Do the same under `Compiler` -> `Gradle`.

Comment: The only option I found was under `Compilter->Gradle` and I already have that unchecked. Also, the complete option text is : `Make Project Automatically (only working while not running / debugging)`